# Xml converting attribute list with indices to an Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Using Java (i'm currently using jaxb2 for unmarshaling xml files), can I unmarshal xml file that looks like this?

```
<person name="John" phoneNumber1="142125151" phoneNumber2="142124125151" phoneNumber3="142124125151"
address1="5 street" address2="35 street" address3="56-th and 3dh street"/>
```

The idea is to get a Person Object that has those attributes (phone & address) as arrays of strings, since the phone numbers and addresses are arbitrary amount. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML structure with those attribute names is notoriously difficult to handle with JAXB.

Therefore, I would recommend to use a more convenient XML structure,
which would be easy to handle with JAXB:

```
<person name="John">
    <phoneNumber>142125151</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber>142124125151</phoneNumber>
    <phoneNumber>142124125151</phoneNumber>
    <address>5 street</address>
    <address>35 street</address>
    <address>56-th and 3dh street</address>
</person>
```

Having said that, you can handle your original XML structure,
but with quite some effort:

In your `Person` class declare a `Map<QName, String>` annotated with [`@XmlAnyAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyAttribute.html),
so that JAXB will use it for marshalling/unmarshalling all attributes
(except for those annotated explicitly with `@XmlAttribute`).

But you want a `List<String> addresses` and `List<String> phoneNumbers`.
Hence you declare those too, but annotated with `@XmlTransient`,
so that JAXB will not use them for marshalling/unmarshalling.

Finally implement a private method `afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent)`
where you shovel contents from the `Map<QName, String>` to the `List<String> addresses`
and `List<String> phoneNumbers`.
As described in [Unmarshal Event Callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback)
JAXB will call this method at appropriate times.

If you want to write XML files, you will also need a private method
`beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller)` where you shovel contents
from the `List<String> addresses` and `List<String> phoneNumbers` back to the `Map<QName, String>`.
As described in [Marshal Event Callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#marshalEventCallback)
JAXB will call this method at appropriate times.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    private String name;

    @XmlAnyAttribute
    private Map<QName, String> otherAttributes;

    @XmlTransient // don't participate in marshalling/unmarhalling
    private List<String> phoneNumbers;

    @XmlTransient // don't participate in marshalling/unmarhalling
    private List<String> addresses;

    // add public getters/setters for name, addresses, phoneNumbers,
    // but not for otherAttributes

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // called by JAXB
    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        addresses = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (QName qName : otherAttributes.keySet()) {
             if (qName.getLocalPart().startsWith("address")) {
                 addresses.add(otherAttributes.get(qName));
             }
             if (qName.getLocalPart().startsWith("phoneNumber")) {
                 phoneNumbers.add(otherAttributes.get(qName));
             }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") // called by JAXB
    private boolean beforeMarshal(Marshaller marshaller) {
        otherAttributes = new HashMap<>();
        int i = 0;
        for (String address : addresses) {
            otherAttributes.put(new QName("address" + ++i), address);
        }
        i = 0;
        for (String phoneNumber : phoneNumbers) {
            otherAttributes.put(new QName("phoneNmber" + ++i), phoneNumber);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

You can test the code above with this XML-Java-XML round-trip:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
File file = new File("person.xml");
Person person = (Person) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try it out. I know the structure of the xml is very bad, but I'm not in control there.